# Need help in dynamically update log levels of 3 web applications deployed on same JBOSS wildfly server

Tags: java, logback, jmx, mbeans

My requirement is to dynamically update log levels of 3 different Java web applications deployed on the same **wildfly JBoss server**. We are using **logback core & classic 1.2.3**.

I was able to update log level of the current application but *I am unable to update log levels of another application deployed on the same server*.

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.